# The microprocessor built up from several hundred to several thousand atoms

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics

Is it possible to build a simple microprocessor with up to several hundred to several thousand atoms? The microprocessor (only integer operations) should implement the basic operations (+, -, *, / and possibly modulo) and have several registers of memory.

Comment: IMO, this is an electrical engineering problem or maybe a quantum electronic/electrical engineering (hasn't born yet - still wondering if one can even call quantum computer hardware electronics).

Comment: And how many atoms need to build today such very simple a classic processor (not quantum)?

Comment: Today's computers are made up of semiconductors. You get n-type and p-type semiconductor. These two types can be made of different size consisting of many thousands of atoms each. A combination of these produces useful electronic components. A simple junction diode can be made by combining an n-type with a p-type. A simple transistor can be made by combining two n-type with a p-type and vice versa. A clever combination of these electronic components creates logic gates which can operate on one or few bits at a time. These logic gates, when combined, operate on numbers.

Comment: To your question, the answer will be "no" if you were looking to build a microprocessor based on semiconductors.

Comment: The Intel 4004 microprocessor had 2300 transistors.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004)  I'd say you'd be stretching the definition pretty far if you tried to call anything much simpler a "microprocessor," and I'm guessing that you'll need at least a few atoms to perform the equivalent function of each transistor, so my guess is you're going to need at least _tens_ of thousands of atoms.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to an in-principle physics question, the answer would seem to be a highly likely "yes", even though as yet it is unclear how such a microprocessor would be realized.

The reason I make this educated guess confidently is the known stunning simplicity of several realizations of Turing-complete machines. I refer in particular to cellular automatons such as [Rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110), which are essentially feedback shift registers, or English mathematician [John Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life).

Given that extremely simple feedback shift registers can realize in-principle Turing complete machines, it's not too much of a stretch to foretell that the technology will arrive in the not too distant future (*i.e.* well within the next 100 years, if civilization endures) to realize these functions in devices made of thousands of atoms at the most.